# React Navigation + redux rerenders hidden screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm having performance issues when navigating between screens using React Navigation + Redux. Whenever transitioning between screens, the hidden screens in the stack get rerendered. I've been investigating this issue and found this comment (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/608#issuecomment-328635042) inside this same exact issue but on an old version of react navigation (less than 1.0). Currently I'm using version 4.0.10 of react navigation and I'm still seeing this problem.

Is there some way of solving this issue thats been added since 1.0 that I'm not aware of?

Should I be using some kind of solution like extending Component to add a state and implement componentDidMount to add listeners for "didFocus" and "didBlur" so that every screen knows in its state if its currently visible or not, and using shouldComponentUpdate to prevent each screen from rendering unless its the currently visible one?

Any help is much appreciated!!